# Python to C# StongBox[Single]

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I've used IronPython to add a reference to a C# dll.  I'm attempting to use a method in the DLL which requires an argument of type:

```
out float tempValue
```

When I pass a python float object to the method I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MeasurementComputing.py", line 20, in <module>
TypeError: expected StrongBox[Single], got float
```

My questions are:

1. What is a StrongBox[Single]
2. How do I create such an object in python to pass to the C# method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a proper target for the out parameter you have to explicitly create a clr reference ([StrongBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) serves as that reference/value wrapper) in IronPython, as there is no out keyword on the caller side (like in C#) that would allow you to do so.

This could look like:

```py
import clr
import System
tempValue = clr.Reference[System.Single]()
```

Directly creating the StrongBox instance should also work.

Please be aware that you could also consume methods, that have only out parameters, not passing anything but receiving a tuple as explained [here](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#ref-and-out-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to "move" the out parameter(s) to the left side of the statement.
For example the TryParse C# function in the System.Decimal class looks like this:

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, out decimal result)
```

You can call it from Python in the following way:

```
from System import Decimal

OK, myDecimal = Decimal.TryParse('1.2345')
```

This way you can avoid using the StrongBox.